# How to return sql to linq or lambda in fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I want to return linq or lambda expression to sql query.
How can do it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select distinct(wo) from TR_DISTAKENEVTVIEW  )
```

I dont find any thing about this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please never just drop SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. And show your own first efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your domain class is **TR_DISTAKENEVTVIEW**

```
int wocount = session.Query<TR_DISTAKENEVTVIEW>().Select(x => x.wo).Distinct().Count();
```

To use .Query() method you will have to use

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

namespace on the top

Comment: Dear  @Pankaj Dubey, I am so late but. Thanks for your helping.